# Create a Geometric Network - Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, geometric-network

I'm trying to create a geometric network in a FILE GEODATABASE, but I get:

> Error: Cannot create geometric network. The selected feature dataset
>   does not contain any feature classes which can participate in a new
>   geometric network.

However, when I do this on a PERSONAL GEODATABASE, it works fine.

Could this be a VERSIONING issue?

Some posts I've seen mention the VERSION toolbar, but mine is greyed out.

I'm on ARCINFO(desktop), WIN10.

Comment: It cannot be a versioning issue because File Geodatabases do not support versioning.  What is in your feature dataset? What parameter values are you providing to the tool?

Comment: So, just for kicks, I created a PERSONAL GEODB. No problem whatsoever. So, maybe this is a permissions problem?

Comment: What is in your feature dataset? What parameter values are you providing to the tool?